# onchange combobox and java scripts

Tags: javascript, html, combobox

I wanna to when i select one value from combo-box it will show me special table and when i chose the other one it shows the other table,but my code doesn't work correctly.

```
<script> 
function bank_state() {
     if (document.profile.nb_shetab_bank.value == 'SAMAN') {
         document.getElementById('auth_method_pr1').style.display = 'inline';
         document.getElementById('auth_method_pr2').style.display = 'none';
     } else if (document.profile.nb_shetab_bank.value == 'MELAT') {
         document.getElementById('auth_method_pr1').style.display = 'none';
         document.getElementById('auth_method_pr2').style.display = 'inline';
     }
}
</script>


<select name="nb_shetab_bank" size="1" onchange="bank_state();" >
 <option value="SAMAN" selected>Saman</option>
 <option value="MELAT" >Mellat</option>
</select>
<table  border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="auth_method_pr1"    
style="display:none;">
  <tr><td>salam</td></tr>
 </table>
 <table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="auth_method_pr2"
      style="display:none;">   
  style="display:none;">
  <tr><td>salam salam</td></tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: what is `profile` ? `form` name?

Comment: Yes...Thank you,I have forgotten that ...:)it solved

Comment: In the second table, there are 2 styles. Is it a typo?

Answer (score 0):

Changing `<table>` display to "inline" is not a good idea and indeed will cause weird behavior. Better change to empty string which will take the default:

```
document.getElementById('auth_method_pr1').style.display = "";
```

That said, your code can be written somewhat different to be more readable and somewhat better. First, send the drop down object to the function:

```
<select name="nb_shetab_bank" size="1" onchange="bank_state(this);" >
```

Now the function can look like this instead:

```
function bank_state(sender) {
    var table1 = document.getElementById('auth_method_pr1');
    var table2 = document.getElementById('auth_method_pr2');
    switch (sender.value) {
        case 'SAMAN':
            table1.style.display = '';
            table2.style.display = 'none';
            break;
        case 'MELAT':
            table2.style.display = '';
            table1.style.display = 'none';
            break;
    }
}
```